# Trying to setup a google service account. Email generated doesn't work

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am trying to setup a google service account so I can access a google sheet from python. I generated a .json file with a client email. However when I share this email in my sheet I get a Delivery Status Notification (Failure):

"Your message wasn't delivered to scantling-io@dnv-strucuture-calc.iam.gserviceaccount.com because the domain dnv-strucuture-calc.iam.gserviceaccount.com couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again."

The email is exactly the one that came in the json file. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck the "notify people" option when sharing the Spreadsheet with the service account, this is because service accounts don't have an inbox or Gmail account associated. 
You could only access to another user's Gmail data by impersonating the user with a service account with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).